# How to launch Java app by double-clicking document on the desktop?

Tags: java-6

What is the best way (or just a way) to have a Java app open when a desktop document on which it operates is double-clicked? [I'm not talking about just launching the app from the desktop, but rather launching it and passing it a specific file(name)]. I assume the filename would have to be passed as a command-line argument to main, but I'm not sure how to tell the app what file by double-click. Ultimately I would like to be able to do this on Windows, MacOSX, and Linux.

Thanks for any advice.